# Get the Largest Number in a mySQL Database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL Database that has a column like this:

```
ID
-----
0352
5432
4382
3520
30593
3992
295
```

What I want to do is search through that column, find the largest number (30593) and store it in a variable.

This database has other columns, the example above is for demonstration only.

e.g.

$largestNumber = GET LARGEST NUMBER FROM ID

How would I do that in PHP / MySQL

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In PHP, we do it like this:

```
$rowSQL = mysql_query( "SELECT MAX( ID ) AS max FROM `tableName`;" );
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $rowSQL );
$largestNumber = $row['max'];
```

Comment: You can also get the value quicker: `list($max) = mysql_fetch_row($rowSQL);`

Answer (score 2):

I believe `SELECT max(id) FROM table` will work.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TABLE`

Execute the statement and assign it to your variable.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This Query**

```
 "SELECT MAX(Price) AS HighestPrice FROM Products";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a single query to figure this out:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-max-function.htm

MySql has it's own Max function that will return the highest value in the specified column.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MAX(ID)` to get the largest value